# How do I get a currently visible (default hidden) slideToggle() .div to close when another is opened?

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

So I have close to what I would like to achieve, including having my slideToggle .divs close when I click anywhere off of the "link" divs (.click, .click2) with one glaring exception...

When I click "Link 1" it does what I'd like and displays .showup then if I click "Link 2" it also initially does what I'd like and displays .showup2 over .showup BUT I need .showup to close so that they aren't both open at the same time.

As you can see with my provided code this presents a problem bc with both "showup" divs already open if I then directly click "Link 1" again .showup remains hidden behind .showup2

Similarly, in the above example if I click "Link 2" first, .showup2 opens but when I then directly click "Link 1", .showup does not appear over .showup2

So ultimately I would like my slideToggle divs to hide when I click ANYWHERE outside of my "Link" divs (.click and .click2) - which it currently does - however that ANYWHERE should include my other script instructed "Link" divs!!  And that is where I am stumped.

Here is code that demonstrates in a very simplified example :

HTML

```
<div class="click">Link 1</div> <div class="click2">Link 2</div>
<div class="showup">something I want to show</div>
<div class="showup2">something else I want to show</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $(".showup").slideToggle("fast");
    });

});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".showup").hide();
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click2').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
         $(".showup2").slideToggle("fast");
    });

});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".showup2").hide();
});
```

CSS

```
body{margin:50px;}

.showup,
.showup2 { width:100%;height:100px; background:red; display:none; position: fixed;}

.click,
.click2 { cursor:pointer; display:inline-block; padding: 0 15px;}
```

Thanks so much for any help! Jorie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with same `class` name of the `button` and `boxes` .`data-target` attr used for target the which element to toggling .

**Updated**

1. Toggle function with each button
2. `Bold` text toggle function added

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if($(".showup").eq($(this).attr('data-target')).css('display') == 'block'){
    $(".showup").eq($(this).attr('data-target')).slideUp();
      $('.click').removeClass('bold')
    }
    else{
      $(".showup").hide();
       $('.click').removeClass('bold')
    $(".showup").eq($(this).attr('data-target')).slideToggle("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('bold')
    }
  });
}).on('click',function(){
$(".showup").hide();
  $('.click').removeClass('bold')
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 50px;
}

.showup{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}
.bold{
font-weight:bold;
}

.click{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click" data-target="0">Link 1</div>
<div class="click" data-target="1">Link 2</div>
<div class="showup">something I want to show</div>
<div class="showup">something else I want to show</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks Prasad!  Only one tiny thing... so we 'lost' from my example where let's say you click "Link1" to open .showup you could also click "Link 1" again to close .showup.  Now a second click (to close) on Link 1 doesn't close the slidetoggle.  And I cannot for the life of me see why this is now happening with your modification!!  Thanks again, you're awesome.

Comment: amazing @Prasad!  this is exactly what I was after.  thanks again!

Comment: as a final finishing touch, is there a simple way to have the "Link 1" or "Link 2" be in bold when the relevant corresponding slideToggle div is visible?  I have been trying to achieve that with .css('font-weight', 'bold') but have not found any success.  Thanks!

Comment: @JorieBreonn See the updated answer.Better use with toggleClass instead of dom css

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you @prasad.  You rock!